# different validation in drf serializer per request method

Tags: python, django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

Lets say i have a model like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    first_field = models.CharField()
    second_field = models.CharField()
```

and an API view like so:

```
class MyModelDetailAPI(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do the update
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do the post
```

The `first_field` is a field that is only inserted in the POST method (and is mandatory) but on each update, the user can't change its value so the field in the PATCH method is **not** mandatory. 
How can i write my serializer so that the `first_field` is required on POST but not required on PATCH. Is there any way of dynamically setting the required field so i can still use the DRF validation mechanism? Some sort of validator dispatcher per request method? 
I want something like this for example:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = {
                    'POST': ['first_field']
                    'PATCH': []
                 }
```

Comment: If the data format is not the same, it is not the same serializer. Simply make two different serializers (probably one inheriting the other, or both inheriting a common base).

Comment: My understanding of serializers is that they are suppose to handle serialization of raw data to a model instance and from a model instance to raw data (JSON for example). The fact that PATCH is is a partial update, you can have many different permutations of sent data - it's not logical to have a different serializer per permutation.

Comment: What do you mean by "permutation"? Objects are not ordered, so their content cannot be permuted. Anyway, what you want here is to add or remove a field. So it is not the same format.

Comment: you're right - permutation is not the correct word, my meaning is in different set of fileds sent to the server from a PATCH request. Lets say i have in addition `third_field` and `forth_field`. In PATCH, i could send only only one of the fields or any sub set of fields to update the model instance. It's not logical to write a different serializer for each sub set of fields that might be sent to the server in PATCH

Comment: `PATCH` is handled by passing a special argument `partial=True` when instanciating the serializer. It will just cause it to be valid even when some values have not been included (more specifically, a value being missing will not be considered an error). The set of fields it recognizes is not changed in any way. If you want to change it, you must inherit it and override/augment appropriate fields.

Comment: indeed - so if i have `fields = ['first_field']` in my serializer, then that means its required when posted and no required when PATCH but when i initialize my serializer with `request.data` that has `second_field=some_value`, it will disregard the update and the model instance will not be changed (not in memory and not in DB)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I need more space than comments provide to make my meaning clear. So here is what I suggest:

1. Different formatting means different serializers.

   So here you have, for instance a `MyModelSerializer` and a `MyModelCreationSerializer`. Either create them independently, or have one inherit the other and specialize it (if it makes sense).
2. Use the appropriate `GenericAPIView` hook to return the correct serializer class depending on `self.action`. A very basic example could be:

   ```
   class MyModelDetailAPI(GenericAPIView):
       # serializer_class = unneeded as we override the hook below

       def get_serializer_class(self):
           if self.action == 'create':
               return MyModelCreationSerializer 
           return MyModelSerializer
   ```

   Default actions in regular viewsets are documented [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter), they are:

   - `create`: POST method on base route url
   - `list`: GET method on base route url
   - `retrieve`: GET method on object url
   - `update`: PUT method on object url
   - `partial_update`: PATCH method on object url
   - `destroy`: DELETE method on object url