# How to display only values in Django Serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am implementing Django REST API framework using the 'rest_serializer' module:

Currently the output is:

```
{
    "count": 86,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/state/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "state_name": "Alaska"
        },
        {
            "state_name": "California"
        },
        ...
     ]
}
```

How do I display just this as a json list:

```
[
     "Alaska",
     "California",
     ...
]
```

Below are my serializers:

```
from .models import States
from rest_framework import serializers


class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ('state_name',)
```

view.py

```
class StateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = States.objects.values('state_name').distinct();
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cam override `list` method, provided by [listmodelmixin](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listmodelmixin):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class StateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = States.objects.values('state_name').distinct();
    serializer_class = StateSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        return Response(queryset.values_list('state_name', flat=True))
```

Comment: added import to the answer

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I would do: as you want a custom serialized form for your states, I would implement a custom serializer:

```
class RawStateSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.state_name
```

You can then use it normally for reading:

```
class StateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = States.objects.values('state_name').distinct();
    serializer_class = RawStateSerializer
```

Note it only supports reading (it will return just a single string for single `GET` and a list of strings for list `GET`). If you want write support as well, you'll need to override `.to_internal_value()` method.

Lastly, if you only want the special serializer for listing groups, but the regular serializer for other operations, here is how you would do it (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38171416/3212865) of mine):

```
class StateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = States.objects.values('state_name').distinct();

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return RawStateSerializer
        return StateSerializer
```